# How to login to console session In xrdp?

Tags: console, xrdp

I want to log in to console session in xrdp.

When I use Ubuntu 12.04, I always connect console session as root  through Windows xrdp. But after upgraded to 18.04 I can't use console connect.
It just says Vnc error- problem connecting.
Please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 18.04 and xrdp packages are not using vnc backend component by default. xRDP package is using the xorgxrdp package nowadays...

So, the first thing I would do is check if you have any vnc server up and running on your target machine. Then I would also ensure that the vnc server start at boot time.  When these conditions are met, I would assume that you can peform your console connection through vnc....

Please note that there might be some limitations in the way vnc works on Ubuntu 18.04..
Please note also that xRDP can be a good replacement for vnc if you simply need to perform remote session on Ubuntu machines. Some limitation do exists as no way to connect to the console + the same user can only be connected either locally or remotely, not on both at the same time

Hope this help

the following links might be useful....

1. [Ubuntu 17.10 & 18.04 – Configure x11vnc to boot at startup](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=12220)
2. [XRDP – How to connect to console or how to connect to Unity Desktop](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5956)